# Find phone number +Z XXX-XXX-XXX from string ZXXXXXXXXX

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I store phone numbers in the format +Z XXX-XXX-XXX and now I have to search for results, having only numbers without special characters i.e. ZXXXXXXXXX.

How can this be done directly in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there only a few characters you need Use Replace

> ```
> CREATE TABLe phone(num varchar(20))
> ```

> ```
> insert INTO phone VALUES('+Z XXX-XXX-XXX')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM phone WHERe REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(num,'+',''),'-',''),' ','') LIKE 'ZXXXXXXXXX%'
> ```
>
> ```
> | num            |
> | :------------- |
> | +Z XXX-XXX-XXX |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM phone WHERe REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(num,'+',''),'-',''),' ','') LIKE 'ZXXXXXXXXX'
> ```
>
> ```
> | num            |
> | :------------- |
> | +Z XXX-XXX-XXX |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=966cd1e4a851de0ed777db93138b82d6)*

Comment: why not `= 'ZXXXXXXXXX'` ?

Comment: @maraca that is also a possible as are all string combinations with strings but i have usually phonenumbers with extensions, which should also be found

Answer (score 0):

Try converting numbers into string and then use the like operator.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE CONVERT(varchar(20), numbers) LIKE '%ZXXXXXXXXX'
```